# Toggle buttons to show a content and hide the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure if my title states clearly, sorry about that. Let's say I have 2 buttons, each with `jQuery toggle()` to show/hide its own content. It works like when I click Button 1, Paragraph 1 shows (I make it hidden on page load.) And so does Button 2 and Paragraph 2.

However, I really want to hide the current paragraph when clicking on the other buttons so that I can show only 1 paragraph at a time. For example, when I click Button 1 , Paragraph 1 shows. Then when click it again, the paragraph hides. But if I click the other button (says, Button 2), I want Paragraph 1 to hide while Paragraph 2 is showing. Is it possible to do so?

Please look at my pen here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzpVBP)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#p1").hide();
   $("#p2").hide();

   $("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("#p1").toggle();
      $("#p2").hide();
   });
   $("#btn2").click(function(){
      $("#p2").toggle();
      $("#p1").hide();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>


<p id="p1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph 2.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have modified your `html` and `js` to be little simpler. Here is how it is..

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn" data-toggle="#p1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn" data-toggle="#p2">Button 2</button>


<p id="p1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph 2.</p>
```

- Add an attribute `data-toggle` to toggle particular paragraph and add its `id` as value for this attribute.
- Add `class` to each `button` so that we can have only one `event` written for all the `button`.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#p1").hide();
   $("#p2").hide();

   //attaching event to .btn class
   $(".btn").click(function(){
      var targetElement=$(this).data('toggle'); //get its data-toggle value
      $('p').hide();//hide all p tags
      $(targetElement).show(); //show only targeted p tag

   });
});
```

#### [`UPDATED PEN`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/YWZgKP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something extensible, you can use a data attribute to identify the paginated paragraphs.

```js
$(function() {
  var $pages = $("p");
  $pages.hide();

  $("button").click(function() {
    $pages.hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data("target")).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-target="p1">Button 1</button>
<button data-target="p2">Button 2</button>


<p id="p1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph 2.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible to hide other paragraphs and show specific paragraphs. Change your jquery code to following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#p1").hide();
   $("#p2").hide();

   $("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("#p2").hide();
      $("#p1").toggle();
   });
   $("#btn2").click(function(){
      $("#p1").hide();
      $("#p2").toggle();
   });
});
```

OR 
you can even simplify the code by adding attribute to button tag :

HTML :

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn" data-ref="p1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn" data-ref="p2">Button 2</button>

<p id="p1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph 2.</p>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p").hide();
   $('button').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-ref');
      $('p').hide();
      $('body').find('#'+id).show();
   });
});
```